# Why does VMware count memory as storage and how can I disable this behavior?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx, vmware-vcenter

Coming from a Proxmox environment to VMware I'm puzzled by this behavior:

[image]

It's a rented environment and I was asked how much memory/disk storage/CPU do I need. I didn't account for memory randomly counting as "storage", so I'm now having issues with enough storage.

How does this even make sense and how can I disable it?

Comment: Here is how to disable RAM swap - https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2146618

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense because of swapping the memory to disk in case of suspending the VM, and swap in case memory pressure on the host is big.

I'm not aware that it's possible to turn this behavior off - but I would argue that it should be a small problem anyway. I can't think of a scenario where I don't want 30-40% free disk space - to handle various scenarios that may crop up.

Comment: In 10 years of using Proxmox I've _never_ had to have random free space available nor pause a server saving the memory to disk. It's a pretty big storage problem, if you're allocated 1 TB of memory and 1 TB of storage which then gets eaten up by actually using that memory for functionality that will never be used.